# How do I export JUST a MySQL query result, not the whole table, in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export

I found a tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ak7oLCgnxyU that shows how to export a query result.

However, when I enter my query, get the result, then click the "Export" link down in the Query Results Operations section, the export page that pops up wants to export the whole table of 60 million rows instead of just the 28 rows my query produces.

How do I make it JUST export the 28 rows in the query result please?

Thank you